# Same value counting at end

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array:

```
$array = array(1,1,5,2,3,3,3,3);
```

I need to find a way to count the amount of times a number is repeated at the end of the array. In this case the number 3 is repeated 4 times.

And if...:

```
$array = array(1,1,5,2,3,3,3,3,4);
```

In this case, the result would be 1 because the number 4 only appears once.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can't you just start at the end of the array and count to the first number that doesn't match?

Comment: Your question is not clear.Show us the attempt first. Lets see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: ([working example](https://eval.in/42615))

```
$array = array(1,1,5,2,3,3,3,3);
$num = end($array); // this will be 3 - the value to compare to
$count = 0; // init count

for($i = sizeof($array)-1; $i>=0;$i--) // loop from the end backwards
    if($array[$i]==$num) // if this is the correct num
        $count++; // increase count
    else
        break; // end loop - not side by side anymore - no reason to keep looping

echo $count; // print the result
```

Comment: Thanks, it`s worked. If in array will be more than 5000 values, this won`t be slow?

Comment: it will only be as long as the length of matching values in the end.. (i `break` it when a non matching value is found) if you have 5000 values but only the last 5 match it will be very fast.. also, 5000 are not alot.

Comment: If the values were sorted, then you could have used a binary search. That would give you a search time of O(logN) as opposed to the above method of O(N). Basically start with the end value  as the right end of the binary search partition and start with the middle value of the array as the left end of the binary search partition. This way, you could locate the first occurence of 3 from the start in O(logN) time.